# How to inject an external-defined class in Java EE

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

Supposing I would like to use a `Foo` class defined by an external library written in **JavaSE** (and assuming that I cannot edit it).

In **Spring**, I can declare this class as bean by writing:

```
@Bean
public Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
}
```

Then, it is possible to perform the DI:

```
@Autowired
private Foo foo;
```

Is there a way to do the same in **Java EE** (if possible, by avoiding the inheritance)?

Comment: Have you heard of CDI? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to know if there is a way by avoiding the inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CDI, you dont even have to annotate the pojo.

Consider that the following has been declared in an external library:

```
public class MyService{}
```

And then in your project, you can have a stateless ejb or just another CDI bean.

```
@Stateless
public class MyController{

 @Produces
 public MyService getMyService(){
  return new MyService();
 }
}
```

Now from somewher else in your controller

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class MySessionController implements Serializable{
  //simple, just inject and the producer method will be called automatically
  @Inject
  private MyService service;
}
```

You need to check on Producers and Stereotypes from the url:

[Producers and Stereotypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkgkv.html)